# PyCharm pip and PIL installation

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, python-imaging-library

when trying to install PIL to my pyCharm project I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PIL
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 23.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\fooBar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject8\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

when I do this the shell output is

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\fooBar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (23.1.2)
```

But get the same error for PIL install, so I tried deleting pip (21.3.1) in pyCharm and reinstalling which successfully installs pip 23.1.2. But then when I retry PIL install i get this error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PIL
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Bpython-imaging-library%5D+ERROR%3A+Could+not+find+a+version+that+satisfies+the+requirement+PIL+from+versions%3A+none

Answer (score 2):

The package `PIL` does no longer exist.

You need to install the package `pillow`, which originally was a fork of `PIL`.

You need to do `pip install pillow`, or install it directly through the IDE into the correct venv. This will still give you the python module `PIL`

Answer (score 1):

Same as @FlyingTeller, `PIL`, written by Fredrik Lundh originally, is an original package for the Python 2 programming language, use in image processing (and that's why its full name is 'Python Image Library'). However, because of the dropped support for the Python version 2, `PIL` was then removed.

Instead, you should use the following shell code:

```
pip3 install pillow
```

Then, when perform the import statement inside your project, simply write

```py
from PIL import image
```

See Pillow docs for more information (https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).